# Rendering vue-carousel-3d only after clicking "inspect" in chrome-dev-tool

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using VueJS 2.5.3. Vue-carousel-3d wont rendering until I click on 'Inspect' (google dev tool). After clicking it renders as I wont. Besides, i noticed, that 'events' in Vue.data is computed as I wont. '/api/afisha/ its my own rest api, its work correct.

its my vue instance and html template. Help me please!

its my vue insta

```
new Vue({
  el: '#ttt',

  data: {
    events: [],
  },
  beforeCreate: function(){
    vm = this
        axios.get('/api/afisha/').then(function(response){
                vm.events = response.data
                console.log(response)
            });

  },
       components: {
    'carousel-3d': Carousel3d.Carousel3d,
    'slide': Carousel3d.Slide
  }, 
  delimiters: ["[[","]]"]
});
```

```html
<div id="ttt" class="container-fluid screen-2 panel" style="top: calc(1*100%);">
      <div class="promo-slid">
  <p>Подивіться на наших котят!</p>
</div>
<div class="slider">
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :controls-prev-html="'&#10092;'" :controls-next-html="'&#10093;'" 
               :controls-width="30" :controls-height="60" :clickable="false">
    <slide v-for="(event, i) in events" :index="i">
      <figure>
        <img v-bind:src="event.images">
      </figure>
    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Vue's document about [beforeCreate][1]

> Called synchronously immediately after the instance has been
> initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.

If API is so fast, since there are no watchers or data structures initialized, `vm.events = response.data` might be override by component set up process.

I think you had better call API in `created` hook

> Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this stage, the
> instance has finished processing the options which means the following
> have been set up: data observation, computed properties, methods,
> watch/event callbacks

**Updated**

According to document, you need to pass props `count` to enable reactive data

```
  <carousel-3d :controls-visible="true" :controls-prev-html="'&#10092;'" :controls-next-html="'&#10093;'" 
               :controls-width="30" :controls-height="60" :clickable="false" :count="events.length">
    <slide v-for="(event, i) in events" :index="i" :key="i">
      <figure>
        <img v-bind:src="event.images">
      </figure>
    </slide>
  </carousel-3d>
```

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/4jvnmz2n27
[1]: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate

Comment: In creates hook its working analogycal. I can output events in template, like [[events]], but carousel dont build until clicking 'inspect'.

Answer (score 0):

As I understanded, it is a bug, however can fix simply by initializing an array with enough count of empty objects. in your case, instead of:

```
  data: {
    events: [],
  },
```

use this:

```
  data: {
    events: [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}],
  },
```